# js/jQuery заменить несколько тегов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код:

```
<div class="change">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>
```

необходимо заменить только теги и сохранить их содержимое:

```
<div class="change">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что следующий код берет содержание первого тега и подставляет его в другие

```
jQuery('span').replaceWith($('<p>' + $('span').html() + '</p>'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("button").click(function(){

  $('span').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($('<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>'));
  });

});
```

```css
span { color: red; }
p { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="change">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
<!--
<div class="change">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
</div>
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/#replaceWith-function, то есть передать функцию внутрь, которая вернет тег и текст из тега

```js
$('.change span').replaceWith(function(){
    return $('<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="change">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".change span").replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<p/>', {
        html: this.innerHTML
    });
});
alert($(".change").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="change">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**vanilla js**

```js
   [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('span')).forEach(span => {
        let p = document.createElement('p');
        p.textContent = span.textContent;
        span.parentNode.replaceChild(p, span);
    })
```

```html
<div class="change">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>
```